# How do you remove a cookie from within a react redux component?

Tags: reactjs, cookies, redux

I am making a simple login form in redux react but i simply cant seem to get it to delete the user token when i logout. i have tried js-cookie, react-cookie and now document.cookie but none of them clears my `sloev_concerts_01`.

**How do you remove a cookie from within a react redux component?**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { withCookies } from 'react-cookie';
import Cookies from 'js-cookie';

import ArtistSearch from './artistSearch'
import LoginForm from './loginForm'
import * as actions from '../redux/actions'

class Root extends Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.login();
        Cookies.remove('sloev_concerts_01')

    }
    logout = () => {
        console.log("removing cookie")
      const { cookies } = this.props;
      document.cookie = "sloev_concerts_01=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 UTC";

      this.props.logout()
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {this.props.me.empty ?
                    <LoginForm/>
                :
                (
                    <div>
                    <button onClick={this.logout.bind(this)}>Logout</button>
                    <ArtistSearch />
                    </div>
                )
                }
                </div>
        )
    }
}
const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
    return {
        me: state.me,
        cookies: ownProps.cookies
    };
  };
  const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
      login: () => dispatch(actions.performLogin()),
      logout: () => dispatch(actions.performLogout())
    };
  };
export default withCookies(connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Root));
```

Comment: Are you sure it's not being removed but then re-added?

Comment: yeah, i have signals on the saga responsible for authenticating and it does not get fired